# Using Async Await in Angular computed signal

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use async await inside of an Angular computed signal?

I have tried to play with that but so far i couldn't make it work correctrly (fetching the value, manipulate the value and returning a raw value to the signal computed result and not a promise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should/can not use async/await inside of computed signal.

You can run async code independently and then `set`/`mutate`/`update` signal or you can use `effect` function which accepts async functions.

I would recommend reading more about signals and effects here: https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/angular-signals/.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very important question. As @kemsky already mentioned you can use an effect to create such signals.

The nicest solution is to encapsulate the creation and management of such signal in a function, like this:

```
function myBlahSignal(otherSignal: Signal<Something>) {
  const someService = inject(SomeService);
  const resultSignal = signal<SomeResult>(null);

  effect(
    () => {
      if (!otherSignal()) return;

      someService
        .someMethod(otherSignal())
        .subscribe((result) => resultSignal.set(result));
    },
    { allowSignalWrites: true }
  );

  return resultSignal.asReadonly();
}
```

You can then use such function directly in any component that has the required source signals:

```
export class MyComponent {
  otherSignal = someOtherSignal();
  myBlah = myBlahSignal(this.otherSignal1);
}
```